# Pointwise convergence: State $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm completely confused by this subject and hoping you guys can help me to clear up my confusion.

So I'm told:

> State $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3n}}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

So I recognize I need to find $\lim f_n(x)$ and that will be my $f(x)$, but I've only calculated limits with a function when I was trying to find the radius and interval of convergence, so I'm unsure of how to use what I know to find the limit of a sequence of functions.

Thus, so far I've rewritten the problem like so:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, I was then planning to use the ratio test and factor out the $|x|$ but I'm not sure of what I'm really doing.

Comment: How do you deduce that $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$ equals the limit of $\frac{x^n}{\sqrt n}$. This is not true for any $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Epsilon sorry that was a typo.  It was supposed to be a constant multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asked is to find the *pointwise* limit of $(f_n)_n$: you fix an arbitrary $x_0$ in your domain, and you compute (if it exists) the limit of the sequence $(f_n(x_0))_n$ when $n\to\infty$. Call this limit $f(x_0)$ (it is allowed to depend on $x_0$, of course!).

The pointwise limit of $(f_n)_n$ is the function $f$ thus obtained pointwise (defined on $x$'s for which the limit existed).

So here, an example: fix any $x_0\in[0,1]$. For $n\geq 1$, we have
$$
f_n(x_0) = \frac{x_0^n}{\sqrt{3n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} ?
$$
You need to fill in the blanks (replace the interrogation mark) to find the pointwise limit on that $x_0$.

Comment: Based on what you're saying it looks like mine converges pointwise to the zero function?

Comment: @the_new_guy Indeed. (It is one of those cases where the pointwise limit turns out to be quite boring, in the end...)

Comment: Just to make sure my reason for this is correct I used the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot0$

Comment: Yes, this is correct -- you can for instance bound $\lvert x_0^n\rvert \leq 1$ to show it for all $x_0\in[0,1]$, if that level of detail is required. As an exercise to practice a bit more: what would be the pointwise limit on $[0,1]$ of $(g_n)_n$ defined for $n\geq 1$ by $g_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3}}$?