# Prove $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3n}}$ for $x \in [0,1]$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta

I'm completely confused by uniform convergence, but I put together the following proof just based on my other questions here and examples I read online.

Discussion: Let $\epsilon \gt 0$

We want to find $N$ so that for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ and $n \gt N$, $\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=\left|\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3n}}-0\right|\lt \epsilon$

$\left|\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3n}}\right|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3N}}\lt\epsilon$ if $\frac{1}{3\epsilon^2}\lt N$

Proof:

Give $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $N=\frac{1}{3\epsilon^2}$.  Then for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ and $n \gt N$, $\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=\left|\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{3n}}-0\right|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3N}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3\epsilon^2}}}=\epsilon$

I'm completely confused by this entire subject, I've been reading the definition over for the last 3 hours and I just do not understand what is going on.

Comment: Your proof looks fine apart from a typo in the second last term (should be $1/\sqrt{1/\epsilon^2}$) (it would also be good to note that you are choosing $f(x)=0$).

Comment: Wait, why a new question -- if the answer in your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862353/determine-whether-f-nx-fracxn-sqrt3n-for-x-in-0-1-is-uniformly) didn't clarify your thoughts, why accept it and not ask for more detail there?

Comment: downvote because [you already asked this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862353/determine-whether-f-nx-fracxn-sqrt3n-for-x-in-0-1-is-uniformly?rq=1)

Comment: @Aweygan the down vote is warranted, I just didn't understand his solution and I wanted to check my proof as I pieced it together without fully understanding any of it

Comment: @the_new_guy as a rule of thumb: if you don't understand an answer, do not accept it immediately -- ask for clarifications. The answer may be correct, but what matters is that it addresses *your* question (with *your* understanding), not that it is correct in absolute terms. I am sure Olivier Oloa would have been happy to explain his answer, had you asked.

Comment: @the_new_guy then why not ask the the person who posted the answer to expand and clarify?  To paraphrase Einstein, "Insanity is doing the same thing and expecting different results."

Comment: @ClementC. thank you guys, I'm sorry I will definitely do that next time.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries -- there is no harm done here.

Comment: If this question was mainly intended as request to check your own proof, you should probably have used ([tag:proof-verification]) tag, see [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info). (However, in this specific case, you could probably have posted your attempt to your previous question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copper.hat has the answer, but you are confused, it seems, about the significance of **uniformly** convergent.

Try your same sort of proof on a different problem on $[0,1]$, namely,
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{(x-\frac12)^2\sqrt{3n}}
$$
again with $f(x) = 0$ as the function they converge to.

In your original problem, if I give you $\epsilon$ you can come back to me with an $N$ such that whenever $n>N$, $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for **all** $x \in [0,1]$.

In the new problem, for any *given* $x$ and $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ such that whenever $n>N$, $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for that $x$ -- but the $N$ you need to give me depends on the value of $x$ I gave you.  This sequence of functions is therefore not uniformly convergent.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see.  So you're saying for it to be uniformly convergent my $N$ has to be independent of $x$?

Comment: Exactly.  That is the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

The uniform part means that for a given $\epsilon>0$ that there is some $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $|f(x)-f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ **for all** $x$.

If $x \in [0,1]$ then $|f_n(x)-0 | \le {1 \over \sqrt{3n}}$, so given $\epsilon>0$, choose any $N$ such that ${1 \over \sqrt{3N}} < \epsilon$.

Then, if $n \ge N$ we have ${1 \over \sqrt{3n}} \le {1 \over \sqrt{3N}} < \epsilon$ and so 
$|f_n(x)-0 | < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

As an example of where this fails: Choose $g_n(x) = x^n$ for $x \in [0,1)$ (note the end point $1$ is excluded). Then for any fixed $x$ (in $[0,1)$) we
have $g_n(x) \to 0$, but the convergence is not uniform. To see this, note that
$g_n({1 \over \sqrt[n]{2}}) = {1 \over 2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|\lt \epsilon$?

Comment: I don't understand your question? $|y| = |-y|$.